# PHP: ftp_get() can download file with same name only once

Tags: php, ftp, ftp-server

I'm having a strange problem using `ftp_get()` on one of the two identical instances. One is on localhost and another on an actual server. I'm using the following to download a file via FTP. Both of the instances download from the same FTP servers with the same credentials and same paths.

```
$result = ftp_get($connection, $downloadPath, $serverPath, FTP_BINARY);

    if ($result) {
        $successfulWrites[] = $downloadPath;    // file name only without path
    } else {
        // on second attempt to download file with same name, ftp_get() returns false
        // this is where I throw an exception in my code
}
```

On my localhost, I can download the same file over and over, and it doesn't matter what the file name on the FTP server is or where it's located.

On second instance, which is identical to the localhost's (i.e. pulled from the same git repo) in terms of code, I can download a file once, but the same file cannot be downloaded again, and `ftp_get()` returns false. If I change the name of the file on the FTP server, I can download it, but after that it won't work again. i.e. `ftp_get()` will return false.

I don't have access to the FTP server log. If it's available, I'm going to try to get it today from the host. But can anyone think of a reason this might be happening? `ftp_get()` just returns true or false without any explanation, so I'm pretty stuck with this.

I'm using PHP 5.4, and I have no idea what the spec is of the FTP (regular FTP) server.

Comment: No, I'm actually not saving the file. I'm reading the content and making updates, but it does not get to that point. Let me update the code, so it includes a little more info.

Comment: If you swap the FTP function call for a console `ftp` call in PHP, does that work in the same server-to-server combination? That would be a good test to narrow things down a bit; if that fails to, the local side would seem to be fine. It would then either be the remote side, or perhaps something to do with the connection.

Comment: I don't quite follow with the console `ftp` call. Are you referring to executing PHP code in the command line? Also, could the FTP_BINARY parameter have something to do here? I remember having some issues with FTP_BINARY vs. FTP_ASCII several weeks ago when I wrote this code.

Comment: _Are you referring to executing PHP code in the command line?_ No, the other way around - execute command line in PHP, using something like `system`. I am wondering if PHP's FTP implementation might be the issue, and since you can run console FTP commands easily in PHP, that might be worth a go.

Comment: Oh what a fool I am. `$downloadPath`! The file is being saved first before being read when using `ftp_get()`. Let me make some modifications to take this into account for the time being and I'll let you know if it's a permission issue. I'm not sure why there would be permission issue, though. The same user `apache` should be writing or over-writing the file.

Comment: halfer, could you put up your first comment here as the answer? The file cannot not be overwritten for some reason, but this is not critical for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, it sounded like `ftp_get` was successfully obtaining the file and writing it locally. I wonder whether due to a permissions problem, when it tries to write the file locally again, it fails. Thus, the FTP channel itself is fine, and the problem is just local.

I'm somewhat surprised at this though, as I would imagine PHP would have raised a warning. Is your `error_reporting` set to allow this whilst you are debugging?